# search for number in txt.file and get all results

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file containing a 30,000-line
I want to search for two numbers designated in the text file ...
And the results I get is a whole line .....
This is an example of the way the search and display the results ...
Please help me, because I need it very badly

An example of the text to be searched inside

[image]

Desired results

[image]

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you.  You show us what you've done and tell where the issue is and we help you fix it.  If you haven't done anything then posting a question here is premature.  That said, you might want to look at the `File.ReadLines` method as a way to read a file line by line rather than reading the whole file in one go.  As you loop through the result you will get a `String`, so your task is simply to determine whether a `String` contains another `String`.  It should take very little research to find out how to do that.

Comment: By the way, when you add an image link and it prompts you with "enter image description here", you're supposed to actually enter the image description there.

Comment: Thank you, Mr ......
I've tried all methods available to obtain such specific results ....
You have to know the question you do not need to be written for me ...
But I am asked if there was someone who has an idea of the topic can help me ...
After all ..... if I got a solution .... there is no need to question

Comment: Noone's expecting you to have THE solution, but what is expected is that you will do the research and do what you think is required. If you can't even get to a point where you can make a best guess then you haven't really tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below could work. What it does is, loops through your file line at a time and uses an IF statement to test if it  meets the requirements. Then once you find the line, return it or do what you want with it and then exit the for loop if found.

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    If line.Contains("Here put the first number") AndAlso line.Contains("Here put the second number")
          'you found the line, now return the line
           Exit For 'Once you found the line exit the loop, as it will continue reading the file
    End If
Next
```

Also this information could have found by googling how to read in a file. [File.ReadLines](https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readlines-vbnet) This link can help you understand whats happening.

Comment: thanx sir ....... thisis what i want :)